# copy $scope object to another, the html of the using is differnet, but after copying, it is the same

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

my problem is, i have a tree element in scope.

with : `angular.copy()` i copy the tree element which i use in a dialog. the functionality of both are different(one has ng-click, the other not and so on..)
but the way how i show it in the view is the same.

then i use jquery-ui drag/drop for adding fields in the copied tree element. after that i save the dialog, and say `treeelement = treelementcopy`. it works perfect, i can see the changes on my real tree, but the problem is, the complete html has changed to the html in the dialog(now it has no ng-click anymore, or has the directive from the dialog for example)..

thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular Drag/drop instead of jQuery it implemented using directives "http://codef0rmer.github.com/angular-dragdrop/"

Comment: ok thanks for your help, but i had to fix this bug today, and change the whole thing is not possible in this time.. do you have any idea, why the html code was "added" or bind to the scope? is there a possibility for jquery draggable/droppable, that the html is not changed after drop it? i need the drop event for getting information about the other element, but i don't want to add id..